# Why do we have to append the /force flag on a "gpupdate" call?

Tags: group-policy

Why isn't the forcing built in? It seems that Group Policy should update itself with any new revisions. Just looking for any info as to what `gpupdate` does by itself as opposed to `gpupdate /force`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gpupdate` does update group policy with any new revisions.  Here's the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490983.aspx):

> Refreshes local and Active Directory-based Group Policy settings, including security settings.

`/force` also reapplies old settings

> /force   : Ignores all processing optimizations and reapplies all settings.

Presumably in case those optimizations have screwed something up.

[Related reading](https://deployhappiness.com/gpupdate-or-gpupdate-force/):

> So which one should I use? 99% of the time, you should only run gpupdate. If you just edited a GPO and want to see results immediately, running gpupdate will do the trick. In fact, running GPUPdate /force on a large number of computers can be damaging to your career. This is because these machines will hit a domain controller and reevaluate every GPO applicable to them.

Comment: Seems you type slightly faster than I can :-)

Comment: @Tonny just slightly more bored than you are.

Comment: Well I wasn't bored. I answer the odd question on SE when I need a few minutes break from my normal work. That is anything but boring. But it does get a bit stressful at times and then the SE break comes into play.

Comment: */force also reapplies old settings* ... actually, it *Ignores all processing optimizations and reapplies all settings*. Due to the processing optimizations, changed settings might not otherwise be applied lest `/force` is used.

Answer (score 2):

Gpupdate without force just checks for NEW/CHANGED updates and downloads them from the domain if the PC thinks it needs them.

With the /force option it will pull ALL, even the ones that it thinks aren't needed. This is to make sure you get the full and most current set.
As this can take considerable more time (especially if the nearest domain-controller is on the other side of a slow network-connection) it is not the default.

And if many PC's do a full pull simultaneously the domain controller will be hit hard too. That is also to be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I use /force is the time savings. You never have to use /force but if you don't it can take up to three reboots to pick up the changes you've made. I don't wait around for users to reboot three times. That could take weeks. /force updates immediately.